# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define

Tags: java, android

I know this question has been asked  here a few times before. But i haven't seen any possible solution yet.
Before i make the project 'Run as Android Application' , if i do not clean it, i receive the following error and have to restart Eclipse ... and clean again.

```
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define
     Lcom/jstun/core/attribute/MessageAttributeInterface;
```

com.jstun.core... is a part of my src folder, of course i can't remove it. And even if i remove that package, another package will show up as an error like:

```
Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define
     Landroid/support/v4/app/ActivityCompatHoneycomb;
```

I've seen this error since updating to ADT 15, i'm using Eclipse Galileo on Ubuntu
Do you have any idea? Thanks for any reply!

Comment: I tried almost everything in this thread but it didn't work. I resolved the issue by deleting the project then creating a new one and copy pasting the source files from the backup.

Comment: refer this one.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34415101/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v7-util-thread

Comment: Look at my answer at following link . http://stackoverflow.com/a/38391449/3702595

Answer (score 136, accepted):

**This is a build path issue.**

- Make sure your bin folder is not included in your build path.
- Right click on your project -> go to properties ->  Build Path.
- Make sure that Honeycomb library is in your `libs/` folder and not in your source folder.
- Include the libraries in `libs/` individually in the build path.

  BTW, you may want to bring in the `android-support-v4` library to get Ice Cream Sandwich support instead of the Honeycomb support library.

Comment: This problem also happened if you have multiple version of libraries included in your build path physically. Removing the unused libraries from `libs` path, clean and save the project, restarts Eclipse and recompile it again do working for me.

Comment: Excluding the bin folder from the build path solved it for me. Thanks!

Comment: The root cause of the problem was that one of the library was using nineoldandroid library as a jar stored in the ./libs dir , while another project was using nineoldandroid by referencing it

Comment: This can also happen when you have something like `Foo.java` in a package and `Foo.java` in a jar in `libs/`

Comment: This error/bug happens when ever your project folder is in Google Drive. I guess it bugs when ever Drive syncs. At least for me

Comment: The solution to my problem was that I deleted the jar files which I copy pasted in project's lib folder. I explicitly imported external jars in build path

Answer (score 58):

I have encountered a similar error today and the reason was that the support library was referenced by two library projects used by my app project but with different versions.

In more details:
My app depends on 2 library projects

- FaceBookSDK 3.0 -> which is referencing android-support-v4
- ActionBarSherlock -> which is referencing android-support-v4 but with a modified version to support maps.

To solve the problem I had to make FaceBookSDK library depend on ABS library instead of the support library directly.

Comment: Yes, my issue was similar. Two libraries had the httpmime library, so I removed one and made it point to the other project.

Comment: can any of you guys explain exactly how you did it ?

Comment: @samih in the example I mentioned, first I removed android-support-v4 jar from FaceBookSDK project lib folder and build path. Then I added reference to the ActionBarSherlock library project.

Comment: for me turns out another developer added a new version of a library jar file without deleting the old one. So there were two jars with same classes. Thus the error 'Multiple dex files...'

You could do a grep -r 'OffendingClassName' | grep jar$ to search for jar files that contain the class name.

Comment: Similar, but I had accidentally added `android-support-v4.jar` to both my Eclipse build path and added it manually to the `libs` folder I created.  Because of the duplicate references, I couldn't compile (and got the error message the OP got). I deleted the `libs` folder I stupidly created and everything worked.  Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I had a similar error "Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/squareup/okhttp/Address;" when I upgraded PhoneGap from 2.8.1 to 2.9.0. I had to remove libs/cordova-2.8.1.jar manually after ran the bin/update command.

Comment: @M.Sameer I use ViewPagerIndicator and facebookSDK_3.5.2. and I remove android-support-v4 from facebookSDK and my ViewPagerIndicator has libs and android-support-v4. So I add ViewPagerIndicator as a module dependency to facebookSDK but there is an Error:(23, 34) java: package android.support.v4.content does not exist. Then if I add android.support.v4 to facebookSDK then this error (Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define) will occur what should I do?

Comment: I removed  android-support-v4 jar from my project /libs while referencing Facebook SDK project.  All works fine now.

Answer (score 47):

Well for me, I deleted the file in the libs folder called android support v4.jar and it all worked out. Goodluck :)

Comment: For me it was a the file **android support v4.jar (1).jar** I just removed it, and cleaned the project!

Answer (score 34):

I had the same error happening and every time I fixed it, it would come back after I restarted Eclipse.

First of all, as other people said, make sure you do not have multiple copies of the same .jar file around your projects.

In my case, I had a main project that used ActionBarSherlock (among other library projects). The trick that worked for me was going into `ActionBarSherlock --> Properties --> Java Build path --> Order of Export` and unselecting `Android Private Libraries`. Then going into `Project -> Clean` and now you should be able to build the project correctly.

Now, for some reason, every time I restart Eclipse, it automatically enables that checkbox, so I have to repeat this process again.

Hope this helps some lost soul out there :)

Answer (score 32):

Go to Project/properties and Java Built Path and unchecked the Android Private Libraries

Comment: Fixed my problem as well!

Comment: But its stopping gcm.jar to work, how to make it work without this error?

Comment: I had error: multiple dex Lcom/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command$1. I got this after upgrading google play to 22.1.1. Deselecting Private Libraries inside google play project removed the error

Comment: You saved my life! Thx~

Answer (score 15):

To me, just go to Project Properties >> Java Build Path >> Order and Export. Uncheck all external library, as the image bellow. It work for me. Hope this help.

[image: Project Properties]

Comment: that was issue for me

Answer (score 8):

I have also faced this problem in my project. AVD is not able to reload assets,lib,res and etc folder contexts.
problem :
Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define `Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl`.

Then,I created new projects and copied `MainActivity.java`,`activity_main.xml`, drawable context.
Then delete old project from package explore,restart your Eclipse and AVD.
My project is now working properly....  :)
I hope this steps will help u little bit  folks..!!

Answer (score 8):

I have same issue, what i tried is:

1. List item
2. Open Project Build Path,
3. Select "Libraries" tab,
4. Remove all library except the Android Library
5. Adding all required JARs Files,
6. And Done!

It works for me, thanks.

Comment: yeah, i just did the same. removed all jar files, added back. in order and export, unchecked dependencies and checked all the libraries added just now

Answer (score 6):

If some of you facing this problem with facebook-connent-plugin for phonegap

try to remove files in bin/class/com/facebook/android directory ! -> and rebuild

Comment: This is the right answer. Explanation is---- The facebook.android is included twice. Once in facebookSDK.jar which is included in your project and once the java files are directly included in your project. removing it from your project is the clean way to do it. all other answers are just work arounds which will not export the definition or something....

Answer (score 6):

As others mentioned, this occurs when you have multiple copies of the same class in your build path, or elsewhere in your setup.

I had added android-support-v4.jar to my libs/ folder, and somehow eclipse added a second copy to bin/classes/android-support-v4.jar.

You can test for this with

> grep -r YourOffendingClassName YourApp | grep jar

Deleting the extra copy in bin/classes solved the problem - unsure why Eclipse made a copy there.

Comment: I tried all the other options listed here, but this was the one that solved it for me! :) And yes, Eclipse should die and Android Studio should be getting its version 1.0 - the world would then be a better place.

Answer (score 5):

I got this error for another reason. I was mistaking adding both the v4 AND the v13 support library. This was not necessary for me since my minSdkVersion is 15.

I fixed it by *only* including the v13 support library. Also, make sure to check mark the library in your exported library build path in eclipse. I also moved it to the top.

Comment: This was what got me as well. The v13 support library *includes* the v4 support library, so dex was showing the multiple class declarations.

Answer (score 4):

Even after going through multiple answers, no solution worked for me.

I deleted "Android Dependencies" from the build path.
Added all the jar files again to the build path and the error was gone.
Somehow eclipse seemed to cache the things.

Answer (score 3):

I'm leaving this answer for someone who gets in this scenario as I did.

I stumbled here and there before noticing that I mistakenly dragged and dropped the Support Library JAR file into my src folder and it was lying there.  Since I had no idea how it happened or when I dropped it there, I could never imagine something was wrong there.

I was getting the same error, I found the problem after sometime and removed it.  Project is now working fine.

Answer (score 3):

The Solution for me was just to do following things:

1. ->lib directory in your project and delete any multiple elements.
2. Project->Properties->Java build Path and delete any Dependency Library was added automatically and not by you! ->Apply
3. Restart Eclipse IDE
4. Now Clean the project.
5. Run/Debug on Device/Emulator the project ...
   Good Luck

Comment: the problem still persist

Answer (score 2):

My problem at first was:

> Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.

1) I Right click on my project -> **Android Tools -> Add Support Library**
(Run my app...Didn't work so I keep it going...)
2) **Right click** on my project again -> **Properties -> Android -> Check Android 4.1.2 (16)** on Project Build Target
(Run the app again...and get this:

> Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/app/BackStackState;

3) So I went to the **"lib" folder** on my project and **delete** the **"old" Android.support.library.jar**
(Run the app and cross fingers and...)

¡IT WORKS!

Hope it helps someone...Thanks people!

Answer (score 2):

I have had this issue and that doesn't mean, that the same library is loaded many times but System is trying to load a class with the same name and possibly same package name simultaneously, i.e.

- `com.pack1.de` and `Class Geometry` of `library1.jar`

and another

- `com.pack1.de` and `Class Geometry` of `library2.jar.`

How should you approach? 
You should analyze which methods are being used, a method of library1.jar or library2.

There are 2 Solutions,

1. Rename a packagename and then dalvik interprets, that they are distinct classes
2. Or if you want to risk, purge the class, which doesn't contain the methode, which we really use.

I hope that has clarified this often asked question.

Answer (score 2):

I removed Android dependencies from build path and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This error happened to me when in my app's project I referenced a Library project in my Eclipse workspace (in my case the Facebook SDK) *and at the same time* included the Facebook SDK as a jar in the libs folder. Removing the library reference but keeping the jar in the libs folder removed the error.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. I had to delete the `.apk` file and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

For me I deleted android-support-v4.jar from lib folder and also removed from build path.

Comment: Hello Rach, welcome to Stackoverflow. Your answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. When answering questions, please supply additional description on how to solve the problem. It will help others and earn you reputation :)

Answer (score 1):

- Right click on project and go to `build Path>configuration build path`
- Select library tab and click on `support-v4 library` and click on remove
- Click on OK

and then clean your project and run it will work   :-)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else bangs their head on this issue like I just did:

My case involved a chain of library projects. Simply doing a project clean on all of the libraries fixed everything

Answer (score 0):

I found below solution in eclipse...hope it works for you :)

```
Right click on the Project Name

Select Java Build Path, go to the tab Order and Export

Unchecked your .jar library's
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when a same library is added into your project multiple times. If you haven't added the library multiple times intentionaly, check out the dependency/private libraries of the libraries you have added in your project, most probably they have already included a library which is causing this conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling to find this is issue. In my case what happened is while copying the apk to email (drag drop) - by mistake the apk was pasted in src folder in one of the packages.
After removing the apk from source folder it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Intellij and it was because the ActionBarSherlock library I added to my project defined the android-support-v4.jar as a compile dependency and this jar was already included in my project so there were multiple copies/version of DEX at compile time.

The solution was to change the ActionBarSherlock module dependency for this jar to be Runtime instead of compile, as my project was already providing it.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that, i had added a lib project(autobahn lib) earlier and later switched the to Jar file of the same library.Though i had removed references to the older library project, i was getting this error.
Following all the answers here i checked the build path etc. But i haven't added these libs to build path manually. So i had nothing to remove. 
Finally came across this folder.

> bin/dexedLibs

I noticed that there were two jar files with the same name corresponding to autobahn Android which was causing the conflict. So i deleted all the jar files in the dexedLibs folder and rebuild the project. That resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To add the myriad of other potential sources...  I had updated all the libraries in my project's `lib` folder but then Eclipse "helpfully" reinstalled all the original libraries.  There was no longer any reference inside Eclipse to these libraries but the external dex-maker program just grabbed all the files in the `lib` directory and thus got two versions of several library `.jar` files.

`git status` identified the new files and `git clean -f` got rid of them for me (though I sometimes had to wait or restart Eclipse on Windows because it still had the files open from the copy).

Answer (score 0):

ULTRA simple solution and finest:

Remove everything in Right Click Main Project's Folder -> Properties -> Java Build Path except Android X.Y (where X.Y is the version in android). Clean, and Build. Done!

Make sure before of that to have a single android-support-v4.jar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cordova, try **cordova clean** command

Answer (score -16):

Modify the maximun memory parameter in *eclipse.ini*

```
-Xmx1024m
```

And restart your computer.

It worked for me :)