# Multiple dex files error

Tags: android, compiler-errors, dex

Hi i am trying to execute an android app in emulator but i am getting the following error.

```
[2013-01-31 11:19:21 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/imageloader/BitmapCache;
[2013-01-31 11:19:21 - LoginActivity] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/imageloader/BitmapCache;
```

I tried all the steps in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray) but it hasnt hepled me.

Comment: see this if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059719/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi i think you have two copies of the jar files even i had the same issue i had two copies ie; one copy in the libs folder and another in the drawable folder now delete the extra copy in the drawable folder and clean build the project and it'll work...

Comment: I am facing the same. I am trying all the solutions but none of them worked. I could not the file-path. Please give me the file-paths where I can find those Jar files.

Answer (score 1):

I updated eclipse (Help->Check for updates) today (31st january,2013) and now I don't see the error. Before it I had error "Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define". Hope this helps.

Or

Try the Below 1

here is a file in bin/dexedLibs The same file exists in libs

Delete it in libs and it should work.

For me it was the android-support-v4.jar.

Hope this helps

Comment: I am using the latest version juno 4.2

Comment: i updated the poste take a look hope this can Solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

This occurs when you have multiple copies of the same class in your build path, or elsewhere in your setup.

For me, this occurred when I had added android-support-v4.jar to my libs/ folder, and somehow eclipse added a second copy to bin/classes/android-support-v4.jar.

Deleting the extra copy in bin/classes solved the problem - unsure why Eclipse made a copy there.

You can test for this with

> grep -r YourOffendingClassName YourApp | grep jar