# Android Gradle build fails due to Multiple dex files

Tags: java, android, maven, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

I had Android Gradle project with number of external dependencies. At some point of time I have decided to extract some functionality to separate library together with some dependencies, which I have packaged using **[maven-assembly-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)**. Then I am including my newly created library as a dependency + remove some of the dependencies already bundled in my library.

The problem is, while building I am getting this error, which I do not understand:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/squareup/okhttp/Address;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

This is one of the dependencies (okhttp) previously included directly and right now packaged with my new library. Library I have created can be found [here](https://github.com/mkorszun/okrest/tree/master).

Here are my build files:

**Android app build config:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenRepo urls: "https://github.com/mkorszun/okrest/raw/master/repo"
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 15
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
//    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.11'
//    compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:1.8'
//    compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.8'
//    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.2.1'
//    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:15.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
    compile files('libs/GraphView-3.0.jar')
    compile 'com.okrest:okrest:0.0.3'
}
```

**Library build config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.okrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>okrest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.3</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>local.repo</id>
            <name>Internal Repository</name>
            <url>file://repo</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.rest-driver</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-client-driver</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.37</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <format>xml</format>
                    <maxmem>256m</maxmem>
                    <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                    <check/>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eluder.coveralls</groupId>
                <artifactId>coveralls-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

</project>
```

And here is dependency tree for my android app:

```
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0 -> 19.0.1
\--- com.okrest:okrest:0.0.3
     +--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13
     |    \--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13
     +--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:1.18.1
     \--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.5.0
```

Comment: Please attach the contents of the build files to your question. One link is a Google doc that requires some plugin to view it; the other is a pom file.

Comment: All build files inlined.

Answer (score 4):

What it means is that that class is getting included in the APK twice, which isn't allowed. It must be that you have two dependency paths to that library. Examine them and remove the redundant one. If you're having trouble finding it, then attach your build files to your question.

Comment: thanks, but still can not figure it out how is it possible they are included twice. I have even inspected dependency tree of my android app, and problematic lib is included just once.

Comment: Have you tried a clean-and-rebuild? Since you've been refactoring things around, maybe your build is stale.

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed?

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059719/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define