# Android - Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define

Tags: android, cordova

I tried run my android app and i got this error.

```
[2014-03-11 11:21:34 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/cordova/App$1;
[2014-03-11 11:21:34 - Android-C2DM-PhoneGap] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/cordova/App$1;
```

I'm using this project for my reference.
http://devgirl.org/2012/10/25/tutorial-android-push-notifications-with-phonegap/

I'm using phone gap for my project. I export external cordova lib project into my android project.

Why it happen?

Comment: Some build path problem,see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059719/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer

I remove cordova-2.1.0.jar in build path.

[image]

Then I remove cordova-2.1.0.jar from libs folder.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You can also remove this error by following these steps:

1. Go to 'Build Path..' then Click on 'Configure Build Path..'
2. Go to Order & Export tab. Unmark 'Android Private Libraries' & Click 'OK'.

Comment: This solved my problem: I added mockito.jar and after restart of eclipse got the error.