# Mopub android integration - MoPubView cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, eclipse, mopub

I am trying to integrate Mopub ads in my Android application. I followed the eclipse integration steps, added the mopub-sdk to my workspace (and the volley jar), and referenced this library in my project.

However,it is unable to import com.mopub.mobileads when I want to use MoPubView. Am I missing any additional dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a few weeks ago now, so maybe you've solved it, but for posterity this was how I solved the same problem.

Once you've imported the project into Eclipse, you need to add the mopub-sdk\src\main\java folder as a source folder. You also need to make sure you have all the dependencies present in the MoPub libs folder. As of yesterday, the dependencies I needed were:

- mopub-volley-1.1.0.jar
- android-support-v4.jar
- android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar

The website lists the annonations jar as well, but then you end up with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26089572/5139606). It's already part of later versions of the support-v4 jar.

I also had to change my compiler compliance level in Eclipse. At the moment MoPub needs Java 7 features enabled.

I felt a bit mislead by MoPub's "hey just download this and press this and it will all work" type of tutorial. That they don't mention dependencies or the other problems seems a bit of a con to me. Sure, most of the information is there on the website if you look in their full integration help, but their basic tutorial makes it seem like there are no dependencies and that their Eclipse project is all set up nicely. Not so.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much @Simon ! I had to add the mopub-sdk\src\main\java folder as a source folder like you suggested. It is now working :)