# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug' while implementing Google sign in for Android

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, google-signin

I'm trying to implement Google sign in for Android and I'm following the instructoins via

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

But while building the application I'm receiving the following error.

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources,
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
>   :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:checkDebugManifest :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2301Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds810Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics810Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing810Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase810Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement810Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity810Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement810Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus810Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareDebugDependencies :app:compileDebugAidl
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugAssets
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugGoogleServices
>   No matching client found for package name 'com.questo.rugved.questo'
>   :app:generateDebugResources :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugResources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugNdk
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithExtractJarsForDebug
>   :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit
>   value 2 Information:BUILD FAILED Information:Total time: 1 mins 39.994
>   secs Information:1 error Information:0 warnings Information:See
>   complete output in console

My top level gradle is

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.4.0-beta3'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }
```

```
My app level gradle is

<pre>

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.questo.rugved.questo"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0'
    }
```

please help.

Comment: for me this error occurred cause of lack of memory in windows os. It occurs when run on emulator and doesn't occur when run on an external android device.

Answer (score 20):

Maybe this link helps you. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798816/unexpected-top-level-exception-com-android-dex-dexexception-multiple-dex-files)

That helped me:

```
android {
...
defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. For me the error is happened while integrating the google cloud messaging service. I added the mentioned configuration `multiDexEnabled true` in app build.gradle file and then cleaned the project to get rid of this error.

Comment: Could you explain why this exactly solves the problem?

Answer (score 5):

This problem occurs because of multiple inclusion of dependencies. You are including a dependency that is already specified in your build.gradle file. For example:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.0.2'
```

the above specification of dependency will generate this problem, because play-services includes everything, including play-services-identity, & so, here the same dependency is included for multiple times.

The recommended option is to only include those dependencies that you actually need. If you need play services location & maps, only include these dependencies as:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.2'
```

Without including everything with 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'.

In your specific case, I suspect the conflict is arising between google-services of the top level gradle file and play-services-identity & play-services-plus in the app level gradle file. Using only those services that you specifically need resolving multiple inclusion will resolve your issue.

In general, you should not use "multiDexEnabled true" if you don't have a strong & legitimate reason. Using it without knowing the actual problem means that you are bypassing a problem. You are allowing multiple overlapping dependencies yielding a potential source of api conflicts & bigger apk size.

Answer (score 3):

Adding

```
 dexOptions {
        incremental = true;
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" // 2g should be also OK
    }
```

in with in android in build.gradle works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem.
Mine was fixed by setting the JAVA_HOME variable to java 8 jdk

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/"
```