# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

**The error**

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

**My app gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'Hidden application ID'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.2.1'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

While debugging, if I set minifyEnabled to true, then it compiles. However, then I cannot debug my application.

I checked this other question: [Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug' while implementing Google sign in for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369163/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexfordebug-while-implement), but there is only one answer and implementing it does not resolve the issue unfortunately.

AFAIK, the error is caused due to addition of too many Gradle dependencies, but I may be wrong (I really hope to be wrong because all these packages are really important!).

Please help me to resolve this error. Much thanks!

Comment: Can your post the error's full stack trace? To do this, run `./gradlew clean build --full-stacktrace`

Comment: @Alex i tried ur command but it failed at the same point and it gives me same error org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

Comment: Please go through my answer as well as the accepted answer on this [Stackoverflow Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37202393/2094075)

Answer (score 50):

Just correct Google play services dependencies:

You are including all play services in your project. Only add those you want.

For example , if you are using only maps and g+ signin, than change

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0'
```

From the doc :

> In versions of Google Play services prior to 6.5, you had to compile
>   the entire package of APIs into your app. In some cases, doing so made
>   it more difficult to keep the number of methods in your app (including
>   framework APIs, library methods, and your own code) under the 65,536
>   limit.
>
> From version 6.5, you can instead selectively compile Google Play
>   service APIs into your app. For example, to include only the Google
>   Fit and Android Wear APIs, replace the following line in your
>   build.gradle file: 
>   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0' 
> with these lines:
>
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.3.0' 
>   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.3.0'

[Whole list can be found here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).

Answer (score 25):

Try

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```

I don't know the reason.
Something about `preDexLibraries` :
https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system/tips

According to @lgdroid57 :

The following resource should help explain what this code does: link(http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DexOptions.html) Property |   Description javaMaxHeapSize |   Sets the -JXmx* value when calling dx. Format should follow the 1024M pattern. preDexLibraries  |   Whether to pre-dex libraries. This can improve incremental builds, but clean builds may be slower.

Comment: Can you please explain what this does?

Comment: I don't know.I just see that in multiDexEnabled .Or you can clean you project and delete build folder.

Comment: Ok, can you please provide your source?

Comment: The following resource should help explain what this code does: [link](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DexOptions.html)

Property   | Description
javaMaxHeapSize | Sets the -JXmx* value when calling dx. Format should follow the 1024M pattern.
preDexLibraries | Whether to pre-dex libraries. This can improve incremental builds, but clean builds may be slower.

Comment: finally this answer was the only which worked for me ! thnx

Comment: @tinysunlight Thanks, Its help me

Comment: I still don't understand what it exactly did, but it worked for me. I added a second activity and changed it to be the main activity; after that I could get the project to build, but whenever I wanted to run it (on an emulator), it would rebuild and fail with that error. Adding this to the app's build.gradle helped. I am using Android Studio 2.0 for incremental builds.

Comment: For me this is the only solution which worked...Thanks a lot.

Comment: 2g is probably enough.

Answer (score 20):

Try adding `multiDexEnabled true` to your app `build.gradle` file.

```
  defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: This answer was enough to fix my problem.

Answer (score 15):

This is the problem about Multidex . You can try to remove some jar, or you can try like this :
http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#mdex-gradle
in app build.gradle :

```
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

In your manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 14):

add  `multiDexEnabled true` in `default config file` of `build.gradle` like this

```
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
       }
```

Comment: This worked for me. Can some one explain why this is working.

Answer (score 8):

The solution that worked for me personally was:

in the `build.gradle`

```
defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

 dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

My response is a little bit old but for my the only solution was adding multiDexEnabled option in defaultConfig like this:

```
    android{
        ...
        defaultConfig{
            ...
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
```

If this does not work for you try adding this piece of code:

```
    configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '26.1.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My error was related to a problem with different libraries versions and this made the trick.

I hope this can help somebody :)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you aren't using two versions of google service.

For example having:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0'
```

and

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.0'
```

Comment: In my case I had to update the versions of other `com.google` libs to the latest version to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem when I updated the Gradle plugin from version 1.2.3 to 1.5.0 as Android Studio suggested. In its [web page](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system), 1.5.0 appears to be a beta version.

Honestly, I don't know what advantages the version 1.5.0 has, but I'd rather wait until there's a stable version.

Of course, going back to 1.2.3 solved the issue.

Comment: I am facing the problem with Gradle 1.2.2, so not really sure if its gradle dependent?

Comment: @SaketJain Have you tried any of the other versions? Are you running 64-bit Java in a 64-bit machine? There are many variables that might affect.

Comment: btw, I tried the workarounds proposed in the other answers (changing the heap size and reducing dependences as much as possible) but none of them worked for me.

Comment: I tried the other answers, but no they did not work for me. That's why I haven't accepted any answers.

Answer (score 1):

**Possible help**

*Tried as absolute last resort after exhausting all other options*

I removed all memory sticks (RAM) but one. I have less memory now but its working again. I can't pretend to know why the build process always found corrupted memory, or if that's 100% the root cause - in other respects the system ran fine. Maybe this is something to try, best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

For me closing all other Android Studio solved the problem.

I had opened 3 android studios when I was getting the error, after I closed 2 I didn't get any error.

No need to add any code related to multiDex !

Answer (score 1):

No need for multitex. For "old" project opened in Android Studio 2.1 it was changing gradle plugin version from 1.5.0 to 2.1.0 that fixed problem for me.

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it! It's a collection of configuration and update. 
Add these variables where they fit in **build.gradle**

```
android {
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
}
```

Then update to Java 8 `http://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-jdk-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/` and all will be solved! 
It's because of the `buildTools` update and new Android studio.
Nothing else will fail.

Answer (score 1):

By changing

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'

to only needed files, the problem can be solved
This Issue is generated because of exceeding files in th build.gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I resolved the issue by combining all the solutions
adding following to android manifest:

```
<application
...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
...
</application>
```

Following to build.gradle app module

```
android {
...

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
...
    defaultConfig {

        multiDexEnabled true

   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go into Build -> Clean and run your app again

Answer (score 1):

Go into Build ->

Clean Project ->

Run project : done

working on android 5.1 for me

Answer (score 1):

just remove both `build` folder in `/android` and `/android/app`

and build again with `react-native run-android`

Comment: can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61510246/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformdexarchivewithdexmergerforrelease) question, please?

Answer (score 1):

Using ionic, i was able to fix this error using the command: 
"cordova clean"

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I delegated my compilation task to the [Google Compute Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41234719/android-development-environment-on-an-arm-chromebook/41234720#41234720) via SSH. The nature of this issue is a memory error, as indicated by the crash log; specifically it is thrown when Java runs out of virtual memory to work with during the build.

**Important:**
*When gradle crashes due to this memory error, the gradle daemons remain running long after your compilation task has failed. Any re-attempt to build using gradle again will allocate a new gradle daemon. You **must** ensure that you properly dispose of any crashed instances using* `gradlew --stop`*.*

The `hs_error_pid` crash logs indicates the following workarounds:

```
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
```

I found that after [increasing the runtime resources of the virtual machine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance), this issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error. I fixed it by just switching the directory. Cloning my project again from my git repository, importing it into android studio and building it. Seems like one of the directories/files generated by Android Studio when building your project may have gotten corrupted. Deleting all Android Studio generated files in your project or doing what I did could solve the problem. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To all who have faced this issue/ will face it in the future:

Click on Build menu -> Select Build Variant -> restore to 'debug'

Outcomment on debuggable in module:app
    /* debug {
                                                           debuggable true
                                                        }*/

Go to Build menu -> generate signed apk -> .... -> build it

Answer (score 0):

Move the apply plugin declaration at the bottom of the file:

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Answer (score 0):

1. Execute: cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-compat --force
2. Execute: cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-compat@1.2
3. Change : config.xml in your project folder use "6.2.3" not "^6.2.3",
   then delete the platforms/android folder, re-run cordova prepare android, and cordova build android

Answer (score 0):

Dont go crazy
I just clean , then rebuild project and error was gone

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when running an Ionic project on an Android device and I solved it by removing and adding android platform:

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform add android
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case:-

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:multiDexListDebug'.

Answer:-

I just deleted the `react-native-firebase` folder which will be inside the `node_modules` folder, that's it then I could run the app successfully.

And one more thing don't forget to remove `react-native-firebase` but not `@react-native-firebase` in package.json file. So that next time when you run `npm I` or `yarn`. This won't get installed in your app.

This package was causing the issue.

Answer (score -1):

If java 8 or above is used then the problem is the libraries we use are incompatible with java 8. So to solve this add these two lines to build.gradle of your app and all sub modules if any. (Android studio clearly show how to do this in error message)

> targetCompatibility = '1.7'
>   sourceCompatibility = '1.7'

Answer (score -1):

Just delete `.gradle` folder from android platform, then re-build the project, the Android Studio will generate it again.