# Issue adding jar file in Android project in Android studio

Tags: java, android, jar, import, build.gradle

I want to add jar file in my project. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16628496/1928265 this is how I added the jar file in my project. When I add jar files, build.gradle syncs perfectly but when I try to run the project, it gives me an error.

For this I searched some posts on Stackoverflow and added **multiDexEnabled true** in buil.gradle(app). With this the app gets build but the app crashes when trying to use other functionality. I tried this with two jar files mentioned in gradle. But didn't work. Where exactly am I going wrong?

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild
:cropper:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:richeditor:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:cropper:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:richeditor:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:cropper:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:richeditor:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:richeditor:compileLint
:cropper:compileLint
.
.
.
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithExtractJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 3 mins 12.068 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'http://clinker.47deg.com/nexus/content/groups/public' }

}

dependencies {
    compile project(':cropper')
    compile project(':richeditor')
    compile('com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview:swipelistview:1.0-SNAPSHOT@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.lassana:continuous-audiorecorder:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    //compile files('libs/itextpdf-5.3.2.jar')
    //compile files('libs/jericho-html-3.4.jar')
}
```

Error Log

```
12-28 13:39:07.829    5804-5804/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.app, PID: 5804
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #86: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #86: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:341)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1951)
            at com.example.app.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:117)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5346)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:341)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1951)
            at com.example.app.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:117)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5346)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.R$style
            at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.getDefaultStyleResource(LoginButton.java:576)
            at com.facebook.FacebookButtonBase.<init>(FacebookButtonBase.java:64)
            at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.<init>(LoginButton.java:200)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:341)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1951)
            at com.example.app.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:117)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5346)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-28 13:39:08.597      915-915/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid parameter app
12-28 13:39:08.597      915-915/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
12-28 13:39:08.656    5804-5848/? E/NativeCrypto﹕ ssl=0x622aedc8 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x6226e8c0 arg=0x0
12-28 13:39:08.656    5804-5848/? E/NativeCrypto﹕ ssl=0x622aedc8 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_ECDSA
12-28 13:39:09.329    5897-5897/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.google.android.apps.gsa.assist.GsaVoiceInteractionSession', referenced from method com.google.android.apps.gsa.assist.GsaVoiceInteractionSession_MembersInjector.al
12-28 13:39:09.724   30617-5935/? E/WhiteAppsList﹕ /etc/trustapp: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /etc/trustapp: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:453)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
            at com.lenovo.safecenter.ww.support.WhiteAppsList.getThirdWhiteAppsList(WhiteAppsList.java:183)
            at com.lenovo.safecenter.ww.database.AppUtil.batchOperateDB(AppUtil.java:31)
            at com.lenovo.safecenter.ww.broadcast.CheckPermissionService.a(CheckPermissionService.java:42)
            at com.lenovo.safecenter.ww.broadcast.CheckPermissionService$3.run(CheckPermissionService.java:129)
     Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:437)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
            at com.lenovo.safecenter.ww.support.WhiteAppsList.getThirdWhiteAppsList(WhiteAppsList.java:183)
            at com.lenovo.safecenter.ww.database.AppUtil.batchOperateDB(AppUtil.java:31)
            at com.lenovo.safecenter.ww.broadcast.CheckPermissionService.a(CheckPermissionService.java:42)
            at com.lenovo.safecenter.ww.broadcast.CheckPermissionService$3.run(CheckPermissionService.java:129)
12-28 13:39:10.751    5989-5989/? E/WifiManager﹕ mWifiServiceMessenger == null
12-28 13:39:10.968    5936-5987/? E/NativeCrypto﹕ ssl=0x613f3170 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x62a45940 arg=0x0
12-28 13:39:10.969    5936-5987/? E/NativeCrypto﹕ ssl=0x613f3170 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
12-28 13:39:10.972    5989-5989/? E/﹕ appName=com.csam.icici.bank.imobile, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger
12-28 13:39:10.972    5989-5989/? E/﹕ 0
12-28 13:39:12.147    5936-5997/? E/NativeCrypto﹕ ssl=0x626807c0 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x631b8940 arg=0x0
12-28 13:39:12.147    5936-5997/? E/NativeCrypto﹕ ssl=0x626807c0 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
12-28 13:39:12.607    5989-6034/? E/NativeCrypto﹕ ssl=0x61bc2878 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x61f56940 arg=0x0
12-28 13:39:12.607    5989-6034/? E/NativeCrypto﹕ ssl=0x61bc2878 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=RSA
12-28 13:39:14.579    6218-6218/? E/﹕ appName=com.google.android.apps.magazines, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger
12-28 13:39:14.579    6218-6218/? E/﹕ 0
12-28 13:39:14.673      915-915/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid parameter app
12-28 13:39:14.673      915-915/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
12-28 13:39:15.828    6295-6295/? E/System﹕ Unable to open zip file: /data/data/com.amazon.kindle/app_dex/classes2.dex
12-28 13:39:15.838    6295-6295/? E/System﹕ java.util.zip.ZipException: Not a zip archive
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.readCentralDir(ZipFile.java:361)
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:151)
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:115)
            at dalvik.system.DexPathList$Element.maybeInit(DexPathList.java:432)
            at dalvik.system.DexPathList$Element.findResource(DexPathList.java:446)
            at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findResources(DexPathList.java:362)
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findResources(BaseDexClassLoader.java:72)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:413)
            at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.findPossibleStaticLoggerBinderPathSet(LoggerFactory.java:220)
            at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:125)
            at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:107)
            at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:295)
            at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:269)
            at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)
            at com.audible.mobile.logging.PIIAwareLoggerDelegate.<init>(PIIAwareLoggerDelegate.java:46)
            at com.audible.mobile.resource.AssetInputStreamResource.<clinit>(AssetInputStreamResource.java:23)
            at com.audible.mobile.download.provider.DownloadDataSource.<init>(DownloadDataSource.java:24)
            at com.audible.mobile.download.provider.DownloadContentProvider.onCreate(DownloadContentProvider.java:48)
            at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1656)
            at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1627)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5049)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4623)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4563)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1402)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-28 13:39:15.838    6295-6295/? E/System﹕ Unable to open zip file: /data/data/com.amazon.kindle/app_dex/classes3.dex
12-28 13:39:15.840    6295-6295/? E/System﹕ java.util.zip.ZipException: Not a zip archive
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.readCentralDir(ZipFile.java:361)
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:151)
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:115)
            at dalvik.system.DexPathList$Element.maybeInit(DexPathList.java:432)
            at dalvik.system.DexPathList$Element.findResource(DexPathList.java:446)
            at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findResources(DexPathList.java:362)
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findResources(BaseDexClassLoader.java:72)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:413)
            at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.findPossibleStaticLoggerBinderPathSet(LoggerFactory.java:220)
            at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:125)
            at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:107)
            at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:295)
            at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:269)
            at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)
            at com.audible.mobile.logging.PIIAwareLoggerDelegate.<init>(PIIAwareLoggerDelegate.java:46)
            at com.audible.mobile.resource.AssetInputStreamResource.<clinit>(AssetInputStreamResource.java:23)
            at com.audible.mobile.download.provider.DownloadDataSource.<init>(DownloadDataSource.java:24)
            at com.audible.mobile.download.provider.DownloadContentProvider.onCreate(DownloadContentProvider.java:48)
            at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1656)
            at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1627)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5049)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4623)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4563)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1402)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-28 13:39:17.159    6338-6338/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.app, PID: 6338
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #57: Error inflating class com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #57: Error inflating class com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at com.example.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:128)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5346)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at com.example.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:128)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5346)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.R$styleable
            at com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView.init(SwipeListView.java:191)
            at com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView.<init>(SwipeListView.java:160)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at com.example.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:128)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5346)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Have you tried this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717886/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexfordebug

Comment: did you try adding compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' in build.gradle(app) or just multiDexEnabled true?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313101/dexindexoverflowexception-only-when-running-tests

Comment: @SomeshKumar Yes I had tried adding compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' as well but didn't work well

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here ,  **USE ONE**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0' // USE THIS
```

You can upgrade your

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
targetSdkVersion 23
```

Did you add this

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Comment: I tried the above changes, but it didn't work. App crashes.

Comment: @JayVisariya On that time share your logcat

Comment: check the question. I have added the log.

Comment: @JayVisariya Its `Binary XML file line #86: Error inflating class com.`

Comment: You can post your xml

Comment: Which xml? Login or Main?

Comment: @JayVisariya Error indicates there

Comment: Yes. Those are errors of Facebook button and another library used in the project. If I don't add the jar files. Everything works fine and no errors. How can I solve that?

Comment: you can use this for testing case .Down step.`compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'` and `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding multiDexEnabled true to your app build.gradle(app) file.

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

and

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    reDexLibraries = false
}
```

Comment: It should say `preDexLibraries`

Answer (score 0):

Use only this code and remove all the library whose related to play-services.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
```

Comment: If I do this, the build doesn't get successfully built. Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: Add **multiDexEnabled true** in defaultConfig

Answer (score 0):

I have found the easiest way to solve this `missing android.jar file` error.
Download .jar file from `https://github.com/Sable/android-platforms` and paste where this (android.jar) file is missing.

Tada!! It's done. Just restart your ide and terminal (if doesn't worked).

This method works on `Linux`, `windows` and probably on `MacOS` (never tried).