# android studio 2.1.2 error (No files to pass to dex)

Tags: android, android-studio, build, apk

I have this error when i try to Build any project in android studio

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> >     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: No files to pass to
> >     dex.

What are the possible errors?

The same is also  in any new project

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.new.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
}
```

Comment: add `multiDexEnabled true`

Comment: I've tried it  Of course , It did not work , A different problem here, I think

Comment: this problem started after i change package name and copy paste some files in one project , after i removed it notice that i can not build any other project

Comment: can u post u r build.gradle code

Comment: ok i updated the post above

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/33717886/5955593 have an answer for you Q.

Comment: thank u kathi , but i see it befor and try it is deffrent error , i am checking some program i installed after last success building

Answer (score 0):

i can not resolve the problem , it is fixed when i updated android studio to version 2.1.3

thanks to all