# Error when generate apk for android wear in new project android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, compiler-errors, apk, wear-os

In Android Studio 2.2.3 create new project for Android Wear

[image]

try to build APK, and got error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':mobile:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

gradle console:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':mobile:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

in Ubuntu on Android Studo i got the same error

Comment: The error encountered seems similar to the one in this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717886/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexfordebug), it might help.

Comment: add in build.gradle for mobile in android{ defaultConfig{ ... multiDexEnabled true }} solved problem , thanks