# Runtime issue when creating map

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using Google map but getting an issue.I have also added permissions and key in manifest please see below for details:

issue :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

Main Activity code:

```
     private GoogleMap mMap;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
  // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
  SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
  .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
  mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
  }
  @Override
  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
  mMap = googleMap;

  // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
  LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
  mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
  mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
  }
```

XML file code:

```
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="com.admin.maptest.MapsActivity" />
```

build.gradle file code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 25
  buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
  defaultConfig {
  applicationId "com.admin.maptest"
  minSdkVersion 15
  targetSdkVersion 25
  versionCode 1
  versionName "1.0"
  testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
  buildTypes {
  release {
  minifyEnabled false
  proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
  }
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
  exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
  })
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in your gradle

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion ..
    buildToolsVersion '...'

    defaultConfig {
       ...
       targetSdkVersion ..
       multiDexEnabled true //multidex set true
   }
}
```

Also check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717886/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexfordebug)

Comment: you may up-vote and accept the answer if it worked @Anjali :)

Answer (score 1):

avoid multidex enable in gradle.

use the required library in your gradle instead of all play services.

e.g. if you are using maps then compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'

Answer (score 0):

```
  defaultConfig {
   ...
   targetSdkVersion ..
   multiDexEnabled true 
    }
```

in gradle app and use this dependency
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'