# Android manifest.xml intent filter error

Tags: java, android, xml

When I compile the codes,I get
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536.

This is my codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>




<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/police"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>


    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717886/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexfordebug)

Comment: Probabaly memory issues. Increase the memory  in Android Manifest android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" or increase the heap size in build.gradle   javaMaxHeapSize "4g"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in you gradle

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately bro :(

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the entire Google Play Services API so instead of compiling the whole package in the build.gradle files try compiling individual services that you require for your project. 
From version 6.5, you can instead selectively compile Google Play service APIs into your app. 
For example, to include only the Google Fit and Android Wear APIs, replace the following line in your build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
```

with these lines:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:9.0.0'
```

You need to check what services you are going to require and compile them accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

adding those play services tends to introduce dex error. First try cleaning your application through your IDE,

if that does not work add this to build .gradle

```
 defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: Please explain, in detail, how this addresses the `DexIndexOverflowException` error that the developer is getting. Also, an `<intent-filter>` does not *need* a `<data>` element, though it can have one.

Comment: my mistake, removed that bit