# Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$1;

Tags: android

Whenever I want to run my project i get the following error

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. 
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException:
>   Multiple dex files define
>   Landroid/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$1;

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.invinciblesourav.flacom"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"    
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] } }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+')
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply pluenter code heregin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please help me.I am stuck in this problem for a few days.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717886/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexfordebug)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. I solve this issue with updating every Google support library to the latest version (27.1.0 in time of writing this solution). Also I updated `compileSdkVersion` to version 27 and `buildToolsVersion` to version 27.0.3. I hope that this will solve you problem.

Comment: Worked for me too

Answer (score 3):

just you have to add multidex true and add one dependency to it. 
check code:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

add dependency:

```
dependencies {
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

and if you want to know multidex in details please lokk into below link :
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Happy Coding...

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$1.class

Comment: target SDK version should not be different then support library so change support.design library version as per target sdk version

Comment: and make sure all version on google firebase dependencies version should be same

Comment: Now, it requires a gradle upgrade. So, how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2):

My issue was related due to the using of different version of same library. One of my sub dependencies was referring to a different version of *com.android.support:design*, so I forced the version in *build.gradle* with

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
        force 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should enable multidex property in your build.gradle file

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion ..
    buildToolsVersion '...'

    defaultConfig {
       ...
       targetSdkVersion ..
       multiDexEnabled true  // this line will solve this problem
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.invinciblesourav.flacom"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] } }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+')
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.+'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```