# Cannot import a Library from GitHub into Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I tried to add this library: https://github.com/WojciechZankowski/iextrading4j into **android studio**, it is a library to retrieve *realtime stock data* from the **IEXTrading API** but when I did, or atleast I *think* I imported it the right way, I got a bunch of errors like `MultiDex errors` and `findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9`.

I tried to use the release version `2.1.1`, then `2.0.1`. Can someone please walk me through the process of how to set it up?

**Error**:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\Ashwin\AndroidStudioProjects\sockettesting\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\sockettesting\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\49.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [49.jar:javax/inject/Inject.class]))
```

I've tried searching for answers on how to solve these errors but I got nowhere, I tried `multiDexEnable true` in gradle and more.

Comment: If you shared how is it that you added the library…? Did you try Invalidate Cache / Restart in Android Studio? Did you restart Android Studio? What did you do? We can’t tell. Not from your text.

Comment: I found this library on Jcenter and then used its gradle dependency, and when I put the code given from the creator to test it, android studio gave me those errors

Comment: Invalidate Cache / Restart didn't help

Comment: try to use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/33717935/5693082.

Comment: thnks for the suggestion but I tried that already

Comment: Did you try clean and rebuild, It is father of these type issues. :)

Comment: Also 1 important thing to check, if it is eclipse project then  you should use file>new>import or if this is a android studio project  you should just use file>open

Comment: I tried clean and rebuild, didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I could not get the iextrading4j library to work either, even in a blank project. I changed my dependencies entry to this...

```
implementation group: 'pl.zankowski', name: 'iextrading4j', version: '2.3.0', ext: 'pom'
```

Then it worked just fine!