# Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForRelease'?

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-studio

I'm trying to release an APK for react native app v0.61.5,
But I got this error

> Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForRelease'

I'm following all answers related but not works for me I don't know why?

I'm releasing the last two weeks an APK and it's generated very well

android/app/build.gradle

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.example"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

...
dependencies {
    def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version' //added this
 implementation project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)'
...
}
```

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

MainApplication.java

..

```
import androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication;

public class MainApplication extends MultiDexApplication implements ReactApplication {...}
```

instead of

```
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {...}
```

Comment: `cd android && gradlew cleanBuildCache && gradlew clean && cd ../ && react-native run-android`

Comment: What command do you use to make the release?

Comment: @Bashirpour the issue was not with `react-native run-android` when I run it before it's work well, but I'm trying to generate APK

Comment: @Bashirpour I'm using Android Studio for Generate Signed APK

Comment: Be sure to read this article again. Because the release of new versions is very different. For Google Play, it is better to have an aab release. https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android

Comment: And you can use `clean` and `rebuild` in Android Studio

Comment: You can also delete the `.gradle` folder for testing

Comment: @Bashirpour Yes But at the first time when we were in v1 of my app I use android studio to generate the Keystore and I have the key but I guessed it's named like this `appKey` without `.keystore`  extension  So is there a way to use this key if I want to use terminal to generate the APK? And for right now I want to generate Apk, not aab, my client want to see it before publishing v2 to store, And yeah i do every single thing you say but it's not solved the issue  :\

Comment: And i got this file  after build failed in the android folder `java_pid1289.hprof` I don't know who's