# Apk build error

Tags: java, android, ubuntu-15.10

I am trying to build android apk for my application. I have successfully installed java [jdk1.7.0_79](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html), using these [Instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre) (in highest voted answer). My O.S. is Ubuntu 15.10.

When I build apk using both the Jdk (jdk1.7.0_79/80) I get same build error

```
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
 com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Note 
1) I have updated jdk location after installing each jdk(by removing previously installed jdk), I have no problem in java installation.

2) I have previously resolved rendering error in layout which is also same as "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0" by unchecking Android API 23:N(preview).

Comment: `File -> Invalidate caches/Restart` then first option - it should work. After that I recomend `Clean` than `Rebuild` project

Comment: After `File -> Invalidate caches/Restart` there is no change same error messages after building project. I have done `clean` and `rebuild` It shows success, but after clicking the run button it again gives same error.

Comment: @piotrek1543 I think jdk8 is not supported by android studio, and please rembember that I am working on linux not windows so there may be compatibility issues

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 15.10 with Android Studio 2.1 Preview (Canary Channel) and  it's using Oracle JDK 8, so it does :-)

Comment: I am working with android studio 1.5.1 is it the root cause of all problems. I would like to add that I didn't had a working sdk so I downloaded a huge amount of sdk data, but cancelled it after android 4.4 install (in decreasing order). I manually updated sdk from terminal.

Comment: try answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369163/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexfordebug-while-implement

Comment: @piotrek1543 I tried `./gradlew app:dependencies` some new files were downloaded, but no improvement? Error persists, What do you think about updating to latest version of android studio as well as oracle jdk since mine is 1.5.1?

Comment: Do you use a library in your project that is built for Java 8?

Comment: No The error is gone now I have updated android studio to version 2.1 and moved to jdk8 same config as @piotrek1543

Answer (score 0):

Check if your build.gradle(Module:app) has compile

eg:
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'