# app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug with multiple modules

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an android application that depends on java code from a java library module, but whenever I try to use any objects from that java library, I always get the following

Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I've looked at the following [Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug' while implementing Google sign in for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369163/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexfordebug-while-implement) and I've tried pretty much every suggestion, but it still won't build. My java library does use the json library that android uses, and I get a few warnings about that, but it says it will just be ignored

Here's my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pwils33.familymap"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries false
        incremental true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':shared')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

I'm using the module for another java application that I've built so I can't convert it into an android library. Any help would be appreciated

**EDIT** I've tried making my application a multi dex application as well, that's not working either, here's my manifest for the application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="pwils33.familymap"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to fix your issues:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Include `multidex` library in your app's module `build.gradle` file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Then enable multidexing in `defaultConfig` section by adding:

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

If you don't override `Application`, edit manifest's `<Application>` tag, and add:

```
<application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
```

If you do override `Application` class, extend it from `MultiDexApplication` class (from above mentioned `multidex` library:

```
public class AndroidApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ... }
```

If you do override `Application` class and it actually extend other class (for example because of using ORM library that often require to extend from it's class), install multidex by calling from `attachBaseContext`:

```
MultiDex.install(this);
```

More details are available in [Google's documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html).

Comment: I tried that, that didn't work either, I'll update the post

Comment: How does this apply to a project that has multiple modules?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. It turns out that multi-dex libraries don't support 1.8, since I have java 8 on my computer, when it found the compiled code from my java module, it was breaking it. I added the following lines to my build.gradle to my java module to finally get it to work

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

dependencies {
...
}
```