# transformClassesWithDexForDebug error

Tags: java, android, python, android-studio-2.3, jython-2.7

I'm developing an app using `android studio 2.3.2`, I used `Jython` also, because I needed a Python class in my app.
I already installed `Jython 2.7.0` and add it in `path`

I tried to solve my problem by checking other questions like :

- [Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717886/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexfordebug)
- [com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807587/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception)
- [Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug' while implementing Google sign in for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369163/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexfordebug-while-implement)
- [Android Studio TransformException : Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915955/android-studio-transformexception-errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransf)
- [Android- Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890257/android-errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexforrelease)
- [com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807587/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception)
- ....

This is my code :

**Interface SA**

```
package com.aso.mdasa.mdasa;
interface SA {
    Set resultCorpus(String DataBase, String polarity, String feature);
    int resultSearch(String tweet);
}
```

**Sentiment Analysis.java**

```
class SentimentAnalysis {

    private final Class interfaceType;
    private final PyObject klass;

    // Constructor obtains a reference to the importer, module, and the class name
    private SentimentAnalysis(PySystemState state, Class interfaceType, String moduleName, String className) {
        this.interfaceType = interfaceType;
        PyObject importer = state.getBuiltins().__getitem__(Py.newString("__import__"));
        PyObject module = importer.__call__(Py.newString(moduleName));
        klass = module.__getattr__(className);
        System.err.println("module=" + module + ",class=" + klass);
    }

    // This constructor passes through to the other constructor
    public SentimentAnalysis(Class interfaceType, String moduleName, String className) {
        this(new PySystemState(), interfaceType, moduleName, className);
    }

    // All of the followng methods return
    // a coerced Jython object based upon the pieces of information
    // that were passed into the SentimentAnalysis. The differences are
    // between them are the number of arguments that can be passed
    // in as arguents to the object.

    public Object createObject() {
        return klass.__call__().__tojava__(interfaceType);
    }


    public Object createObject(Object arg1) {
        return klass.__call__(Py.java2py(arg1)).__tojava__(interfaceType);
    }

    Object createObject(Object arg1, Object arg2) {
        return klass.__call__(Py.java2py(arg1), Py.java2py(arg2)).__tojava__(interfaceType);
    }

    public Object createObject(Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3)
    {
        return klass.__call__(Py.java2py(arg1), Py.java2py(arg2),
                Py.java2py(arg3)).__tojava__(interfaceType);
    }

    private Object createObject(Object args[], String keywords[]) {
        PyObject convertedArgs[] = new PyObject[args.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            convertedArgs[i] = Py.java2py(args[i]);
        }

        return klass.__call__(convertedArgs, keywords).__tojava__(interfaceType);
    }

    public Object createObject(Object... args) {
        return createObject(args, Py.NoKeywords);
    }

}
```

**SAPython.py**

```
from com.aso.mdasa.mdasa import SA
# Building object that subclasses a Java interface

from senticnet.senticnet import Senticnet
import pymysql
import pandas as pd
import sys
class SAPython (SA) :

    __sn = Senticnet('ar')


    def __init__(DBase) :
        self.__connect(DBase)

    def resultCorpus (self, polarity, feature = None):
        result = {}
        .....
        return result    

    def resultSearch (self, tweet) :
        return self.__calcTweetPolarity(tweet, len(tweet))

    ....
```

**class ResultSearch**

```
public class ResultSearch extends FragmentActivity{

    private String search;
    private ImageView img ;
    public static final int[] photos = {
            R.drawable.v_bad,
            R.drawable.bad,
            R.drawable.good,
            R.drawable.v_good } ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.result_search);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        search = getIntent().getStringExtra("text");
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        sentimentAnalysis();
    }

    public void sentimentAnalysis() {

        SentimentAnalysis sentimentA = new SentimentAnalysis(
                SA.class, "SAPython", "SentimentAnalysis");

        SA sa = (SA) sentimentA.createObject();

        double result = sa.resultSearch(search);

        if (result < -0.5)
            img.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(photos[0]));
        if (result >= -0.5 && result < 0)
            img.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(photos[1]));
        if (result >= 0 && result < 0.5)
            img.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(photos[2]));
        if (result >= 0.5)
            img.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(photos[3]));
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>     com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex
>     process
> - Try: Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Exception is: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.    at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:196)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:50)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:75)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)    at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
>     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>     com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex
>     process   at
>     com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
>     at
>     com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:176)
>     at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:163)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
>     ... 78 more Caused by:
>     com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex
>     process   at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform.transform(DexTransform.java:453)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:185)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:181)
>     at
>     com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
>     ... 85 more Caused by:
>     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex
>     process   at
>     com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.dexInProcess(DexByteCodeConverter.java:180)
>     at
>     com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.runDexer(DexByteCodeConverter.java:158)
>     at
>     com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.convertByteCode(DexByteCodeConverter.java:143)
>     at
>     com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.convertByteCode(AndroidBuilder.java:1345)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform.transform(DexTransform.java:279)
>     ... 88 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex
>     process   at
>     com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.dexInProcess(DexByteCodeConverter.java:178)
>     ... 92 more Caused by:
>     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex
>     process   at
>     com.android.builder.internal.compiler.DexWrapper$DexProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(DexWrapper.java:117)
>     at
>     com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.lambda$dexInProcess$0(DexByteCodeConverter.java:175)

This is my *gradle.gradle* :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aso.mdasa.mdasa"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
        compileOptions.encoding = 'UTF8'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.7'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar')
}
```

and this *my gradle.properties* :

```
ject-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608M -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
```