# Gradle build failed in Android Studio 1.5.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm unable to run my app. Every time I'm trying to run my app in emulator Android studio shows me following error.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Here's my `build.gradle` files.
`build.gradle(app)`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gripxtech.kasim.unipayretailer"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.malinskiy:superrecyclerview:1.1.1'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'com.codinguser.android:contactpicker:3.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.0'
    compile project(':materialdatetimepick')
}
```

`build.gradle(Project)`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I've already tried to apply solution from many question similar to mine but, still I can't solve my issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project?

Comment: Yes, I've tried cleaning than rebuilding project. but, that doesn't work for me. currently I'm trying creating new project than copying all my files in that newly created project. wish that will work for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
...
defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Here you would find an explanation why this error happened:
[UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798816/unexpected-top-level-exception-com-android-dex-dexexception-multiple-dex-files)

If it wouldn't work, please delete all files and folders from:

```
YOUR_APP_NAME\app\build\intermediates
```

It sometimes happens when you have duplicated dependencies with different versions

Try this command and check if there something twice:

```
./gradlew dependencies
```

Hope it help

Comment: it Works like charm. Thanks a ton