# Android Native Mobile First depends on too many libs?

Tags: android, dependencies, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-mobile-services

I am currently playing around with Bluemix and Mobile First Platform researching whether it might fit my needs as backend for the Android app I am developing.

Starting from an empty Android project I have only successfully implemented `IBM Push Notification`. I followed this official [sample](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-android-hellopush).

My next step was to implement the lib [Couchbase Lite for Android](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android) (so far the data I will used is placed in my own CouchDB service). To do so I added the dependency to Gradle so the file looked like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "es.woozycoder.android.bluemixpayaround"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

    compile group: 'com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android',
            name:'core',
            version: '1.+',
            ext:'aar',
            transitive: true

    compile group: 'com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android',
            name: 'push',
            version: '1.+',
            ext: 'aar',
            transitive: true

    compile 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:1.1.0'
}
```

What is my surprise when I compile and see the following error which I believe is closely related to [too many dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33786747/815227).

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_72\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 2

The answer linked above suggests that Google Play Services dependency would be the problem and I agree as **the lib Push depends on the whole google-services lib** instead of only the specific ones (I guess those would be *gcm* (com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm) and *base* (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base)).

**Has anyone an idea of what could be the solution to this issue?**

**UPDATE**

1. This is a native Gradle-based Android Application created with Android Studio.
2. The problem arises at the moment I add the `couchbase-lite-android` dependency.
3. I have seen that the lib `googleauthentication` also depends on the whole lib `com.google.android.gms:play-services` instead of the specific ones only.

**UPDATE 2**

[Here](https://github.com/woozy-coder/HelloPush.git) is the Github project. Pull it and compile. You'll see that it compiles and runs successfully. But, now uncomment the couchbase-lite dependecy in the module's [gradle.build](https://github.com/woozy-coder/HelloPush/blob/master/app/build.gradle). Now, build the project. It will fail.

Comment: Does this only happen after you include the last dependency for CouchDB? Were you able to run the hello-push sample successfully?

Comment: After work (this is a personal project) I will push the *playaround* project to Github. I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your question if you are actually developing a Hybrid Android app or a native one...

If you are developing a native app and adding the MFP SDK to it, then you should create a Gradle-based Android project in Android Studio.

If you are developing a Hybrid Android app in MobileFirst Studio then you have two options:

1. If using MPF 7.0/7.1, try adding ProGuard support which will help in decrease the amount of files and maybe solve this
2. Import the generated Android project into Android Studio and convert it to a Gradle-based project, and then add Google Play Services. Of course, the next time you will build the app in MFP Studio, it will not be Gradle-based, so you will have to repeat this step.

As you may have guessed, MFP does not support Gradle-based projects at this time.

Comment: I do have created a Gradle-based Android project in Android Studio.