# com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, google-play-services

i just added classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' and updated google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0 to 9.0.0 and i get this Error 
please tell me how to solve it?

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807587/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception), by adding `multiDexEnabled true` to your app build.gradle file.

```
defaultConfig {
multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Also double check your .jar file and lib that appearing multiple times in your project.

For more information and other solutions, check this related SO questions:

- [UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798816/unexpected-top-level-exception-com-android-dex-dexexception-multiple-dex-files)
- [Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917696/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-com-android-ide-common-process)