# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForRelease'

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, proguard, android-proguard

I am getting this error in **gradle console** when I remove the line `--dontobfsucate` from my proguard rule file. Otherwise I am able to successfully generate the apk.
I was previously facing this problem before [My Previous Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42483279/getting-errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithmultidexlistfo). But i was able to resolve that by options ***--stacktrace --debug***.

I think I have removed redundant grade redundancies.

```
13:10:41.397 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
13:10:41.397 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
13:10:41.397 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
13:10:41.397 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForRelease'.
13:10:41.398 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException (no error message)
13:10:41.398 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
13:10:41.398 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
13:10:41.398 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForRelease'.
 13:10:41.398 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
13:10:41.399 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
13:10:41.399 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
13:10:41.399 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
13:10:41.399 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at  org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
13:10:41.399 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
13:10:41.399 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
13:10:41.399 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
13:10:41.399 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
13:10:41.399 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
13:10:41.399 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
13:10:41.399 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
13:10:41.399 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
 13:10:41.399 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
13:10:41.399 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
13:10:41.399 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
13:10:41.399 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
13:10:41.399 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
13:10:41.399 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
13:10:41.400 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
```