# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/util/ThreadUtil$MainThreadCallback;

Tags: android, dex

I am getting unable to execute dex : multiple dex file error.

**Console Error:**

```
[2015-12-22 16:39:38 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/util/ThreadUtil$MainThreadCallback;
[2015-12-22 16:39:38 - Talkr] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/util/ThreadUtil$MainThreadCallback;
```

below I have posted the screenshot for order and export.I cant check the android private libraries.if i checked it,My application gets slow and I cant run the application.

**Order and Export:**

[image]

**Edit:** If I uncheck all my libraries,multiple dex error would be resolved.But I am getting Thread suspended exception at **Debug**.

Below I have posted that debug error.

[image]

Anyone know how to solve this one.Thank You.

Comment: yah move to gradle & android studio :-) other than that - two libraries are declaring the class `android/support/v7/util/ThreadUtil$MainThreadCallback` try unticking your `v7-recyclerview` dep and see if someone else is already pulling that in.  (In gradle you would type `gradle dependencies` to see who is using what

Comment: You might want to make sure that no more libraries are using supportV7 or at least you are using the same lib version, this problem might be because you have multiple version of libraries included in your build path physically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Eclipse :**

- These error occurred because I was updated my android sdk to 23
  latest version and in extras Google play services,repository at the
  middle of my project.
- Due to the conflict between my updated google play services version
  and appcompat v7 between my lower version,multi dex error would be
  occurred.
- To avoid these error dont update an sdk or google play
  services at the middle of project once if you started the
  project.There will be a conflict configuration between sdk updated
  version and also in extras google play services between your project.

**Edit:** Always use Android studio to avoid this kind of multidex issue.

Comment: I'm using Android Studio but still managed to get this error :D. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44084767/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v7-util-threadutilmainthreadcallback)