# DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/impl/cookie/BrowserCompatSpec;

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, twilio, twilio-api

I'm developing an Android app in which I wanna generate number programmatically for each user. I'm using below (Twilio) dependency in my project.

```
compile group: 'com.twilio.sdk', name: 'twilio', version: '7.17.0'
```

When I try to run the app, it gives me following error(See attached image).
 Any solution?[image]

Comment: Please show your entire Gradle file and tell us if you're using any JAR files

Comment: I'm not using any JAR file

Comment: Again, please [edit] your question to include the entire Gradle files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059719/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define)